# I have a question about the erlang_ls.config file. Can anyone offer some assistance?

Tags: visual-studio-code, erlang, erlang-ls

I’m using the VS CODE Erlang LS plugin on a Windows 10 system, with Erlang installed at ‘C:\Program Files\erl-23.2’.
All my code is in the ‘D:\mycode’ folder, with ‘.hrl’ files stored in ‘D:\mycode\include’ and ‘.erl’ files in ‘D:\mycode\src’.
When I open the ‘mycode’ folder in VS CODE, how should I configure the erlang_ls.config file?

I’m not quite sure how to configure it, and it always fails. I get an error message: “Issue in include file(11):include file,” and the code auto-completion doesn’t work. It would be great if there was a complete reference to follow.